# Use one method in another method

Tags: java, variables, methods, calculator

so this has probably been asked before but i cant really understand all the information i have been reading online.

```
public static void balanceSheet(){
  //Put in the Company u want to get the data from
  Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter your Symbol: ");
  String symbol= scan.nextLine();

  //Diffrent Websites to visit and get the Data
  String url = ("http://www.morningstar.com/stocks/XNAS/"+symbol+"/quote.html");
  driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[(@id = 'quote_quicktake')]//iframe")));
  String currPrice = driver.findElement(By.id("last-price-value")).getText();
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

  System.out.println("Current Share Pirce: "+currPrice+"$");
}
```

how do i get the value of String currPrice inside the calCulator method so i can calculate it with other numbers?

```
public void calCulator() {
  Scanner calCu = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Do you want to Calculate the Value?: ");
  String calculator = calCu.next();

  if(calculator.equals("Yes")) {
    System.out.println("the Calculation is: ");
  }

  else {
    System.out.println("ok");
  }
}
```

Comment: Pass that value as a parameter to `calCulator()` method??

Comment: or store `currPrice` as a field

Comment: can i have an example? this is my first program so i am pretty fresh with java

Comment: _"so this has probably been asked before "_ -- yes, about a dozen times in the last 2 weeks...  StackOverflow is not a tutorial site, please visit the [help] and read [ask]

Comment: @BrudgeKisekka - add the full code, that calls `balanceSheet` and `calCulator`. Can't really understand what you are trying to do here by with `currPrice`

Comment: My public balanceSheet scrapes the internet for key data like the currPrice then i want the data gatherd in the balancesheet to be added into my calCulator method and calculate the result im looking for and print the result

Answer (score 0):

ok i got the answer i wanted anyways after 15 hours of pure looking at tutorials it was really easy, it was just me that is slow in the head but the thing that i did was

```
public class Webscraper {

    String currentPrice; <<<<<< ADDED THAT STRING TO MY CLASS

    public void balanceSheet(){
      //Put in the Company u want to get the data from
      Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter your Symbol: ");
      String symbol= scan.nextLine();

      //Diffrent Websites to visit and get the Data
      String url = ("http://www.morningstar.com/stocks/XNAS/"+symbol+"/quote.html");
      driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[(@id = 'quote_quicktake')]//iframe")));
      String currPrice = driver.findElement(By.id("last-price-value")).getText();
      driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

      System.out.println("Current Share Pirce: "+currPrice+"$");
      currentPirce = currPrice; <<<<<< ADDED THAT SO THAT THE CLASS STRING WOULD GET ITS VALUE
    }

    public void calCulator() {
      Scanner calCu = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Do you want to Calculate the Value?: ");
      String calculator = calCu.next();

      if(calculator.equals("Yes")) {
        System.out.println("the Calculation is: "currentPrice); <<<<<< NOW I CAN GET THE VALUE
      }

      else {
        System.out.println("ok");
      }
    }
```

thank you guys for the help anyways u pointed me in the right direction hope this will help some other soul that has the same problem

Answer (score -1):

Take `currPrice` as member variable of class, then you can use it in other method of class like below.

```
public class Culator {
    // Take "currPrice" as member variable of class
    public static String currPrice = "";


    public static void balanceSheet(){

        //Put in the Company u want to get the data from
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your Symbol: ");
        String symbol= scan.nextLine();

        //Diffrent Websites to visit and get the Data
        String url = ("http://www.morningstar.com/stocks/XNAS/"+symbol+"/quote.html");

        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[(@id = 'quote_quicktake')]//iframe")));
        currPrice = driver.findElement(By.id("last-price-value")).getText();

        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

        System.out.println("Current Share Pirce: "+currPrice+"$");
    }


     public void calCulator()
     {
         Scanner calCu = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Do you want to Calculate the Value?: ");
         String calculator = calCu.next();

         if(calculator.equals("Yes")){
             System.out.println("the Calculation is: ");
         } else {
             System.out.println("ok");
         }
         // Now You can use "currPrice" in this method
     }

}
```

Comment: but when i try that i always get the result Null back and not the currPrice declared in the public static void balanceSheet()

Comment: `balanceSheet` is a static method, you can't access instance variable `currPrice` in there

Comment: Update your code as my updated answer. You need to first call balanceSheet(). So,  `currPrice` is calculated first then you can use that variable value in other method.

Comment: i did update it like u said the result is 
the Calculation is: 
empty result